# Automate Word Macro code to replace string of operators like "^=" with a hyphen?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to find all instances of strings "^=" or "=^" or "^+" and replace them  by " - " (space-hyphen-space). So far I have tried using the Regex code from another one of the stackoverflow posts but I am really struggling and trying to match expressions. Please find my attempts and share how I can write VB macro code to automate the process. Thank you for your help!

```
With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^+"
        .Replacement.Text = " -- "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need a macro for that. Try a *wildcard* Find/Replace where:

```
Find = [^94=][^94=+]
Replace = ^32-^32
```

To lengthen the hyphenation, you could use and of:

```
Replace = ^32--^32
Replace = ^32^=^32; or
Replace = ^32^+^32,
```

the latter two of which change the hyphen to an en-dash or em-dash, respectively.

If you want to keep the hyphenation together with whatever precedes it, change the first ^32 to ^s.

Or, as a macro:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "[^94=][^94=+]"
    .Replacement.Text = " - "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

As with manual *wildcard* Find/Replace you could lengthen the hyphenation with any of:

```
    .Replacement.Text = " -- "
    .Replacement.Text = " ^= "
    .Replacement.Text = " ^+ "
```

Again, if you want to keep the hyphenation together with whatever precedes it, change the first replacement space in the code to ^s.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you explain the way you came up  with the expression for .Text i,e [^94=][^94=+].

Comment: The ^94 is the ASCII code for the caret (^). The Find expression has two parts: [^94=] and [^94=+]. The first part tells Word to find either of ^ or =. The second part tells Word to find any of ^, = or +. Both parts must be satisfied. Theoretically, it would also find ^^ and =+. The ^32  is just the ASCII code for a space - which is hard to represent otherwise in the manual Replace expression.

Comment: in replacement text how can I replace it with (space)(hyphen)(hyphen)(space)? You replace it with (space)(hyphen)(space). When I try an expression like ^45- in Replacement.Text, it gives a double spacing between the hyphens. Happy New Year!

Comment: thank you for your help! Could you also please have a look at my other question if you get some free time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65657565/word-macro-to-change-footer-font-size-and-set-it-different-from-the-different-he