# Word Macro to change footer font size and set it different from the different headers and the body in the documents?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to set a different font size for the footer in the document from the rest of the body. Moreover, how can I change font size of certain headings in the document without having knowledge of what the heading size might be? Any help would be appreciated! I am posting what I tried so far. Thank you!

```
Sub MyMacro()
 

    Selection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = LinesToPoints(1.5)
    
    
    Set myRange =ActiveDocument.Sections.First.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    With myRange.Font
        .Name = "Palatino Linotype"
        .Size = 8
    End With

 
End Sub
```

```
Sub NewMacro()

 With ActiveDocument.Styles("Footer").Font
        .Name = "Palatino Linotype"
        .Size = 8.5
 End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to document reformatting is poor practice and is prone to lead to document corruption. You should instead modify the Styles used in the document. For example:

```
With ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal").Font
  .Name = "Palatino Linotype"
  .Size = 11
End With
```

For your Header/Footer content, achieving the desired results there may necessitate the use of different Styles than you use in the document body.

Especially with the use of Styles, but even with your present approach, there is no need to Select anything or to switch views. For example:

```
ActiveDocument.Sections.First.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Style = "My Style"
```

Comment: i agree completely. Word has a style that is used in Footers by default. By coincidence, the name of the style is "Footer." There is a corresponding Header style.

Comment: @macropod I don't understand how to manipulate styles. What's Normal Styles? I tried using normal and some other methods to manipulate the font size of footer and body differently as updated in my question. However, neither makes the required changes even with Charles suggestion of using footer in styles

Comment: The code I posted already shows how one might modify/apply a Word Style. The use of Styles is fundamental to Word. It is *impossible* to use Word without also using (or abusing) Styles. You should learn the basics of how Word works...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comments I got to explore styles more and made some progress! I really appreciate your help. I hope I'm not being annoying but could you also look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65785357/word-macro-replace-superscript-of-footnote-reference-in-the-footnotes-only