# Replace superscript of Footnote reference in the footnotes only

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, formatting

I am trying to convert the footnotes into a specific font style (Chicago Style). I have managed to change font of footnotes separately but I can't refer to the footnote reference number in the footnotes of the pages. I am trying to convert the superscript into a normal number and can't get the code to work for some reason. It keeps changing the superscripts in the rest of the body of the document which is not what I am looking for because reference number in body are kept superscripted. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
   With ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal").Font
        .Name = "Palatino Linotype"
        .Size = 11
    End With
    
    Dim afn As Footnote
    For Each afn In ActiveDocument.Footnotes
        With afn.Range
            .Font.Size = 8.5
            .Font.Name = "Palatino Linotype"
            .Text = .Text
        End With
    Next afn
    
    Dim f As Footnote

    For Each f In ActiveDocument.Footnotes
      With f.Range.Characters(1)
        .Font.Superscript = False
      End With
    Next
        
    'With Selection
       '.Paragraphs(1).Range.Font.Reset
       '.Paragraphs(1).Range.Characters(2) = ""
       '.InsertAfter "." & vbTab
       '.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    'End With
        
    
    'For Each afn In ActiveDocument.Footnotes
        'With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
         '.ClearFormatting
         '.Replacement.ClearFormatting
         '.Font.Superscript = True
         '.Format = True
         '.Text = ""
         '.Replacement.Text = "^&"
         '.Replacement.Font.Superscript = False
         '.MatchWildcards = True
         '.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        'End With
    'Next afn
    
    
    'Make Footnotes non-superscripted
    'With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        '.ClearFormatting
        '.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        '.Font.Superscript = True
        '.Format = True
        '.Text = ""
        '.Replacement.Text = "^&"
       ' .Replacement.Font.Superscript = False
      '  .MatchWildcards = True
     '   .Execute
```

Answer (score 1):

A Word document is constructed from a number of Story Ranges, one of which is the Footnotes Story.
To make the footnote number non-superscript just in the footnotes you can execute a find and replace in the Footnotes Story as below.

```
Sub ApplyChicagoStyle()
   With ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdFootnotesStory).Find
      .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleFootnoteReference)
      .Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleFootnoteText)
      .Replacement.Font.Superscript = False
      .Format = True
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   End With
End Sub
```

You would need to run this after you have added all the footnotes to your document.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @BilalHussain - please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Your post is ambiguous:

• Are you trying to modify the footnotes, or the footnote references?

• Does Chicago actually *require* a specific font for footnotes, or a different font for the footnote reference in the footer from the footnote reference in the document body? I cannot find any documentation that suggests that either proposition is the case.

If it's the footnotes you want to change, change the Footnote Style. No code required.

Alternatively, if you want to remove the superscripting from the footnote references in the footnotes, but not in the document body, you could use a Find/Replace there. As a macro, this would be:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdFootnotesStory).Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^2"
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Replacement.Font.Superscript = False
    .Forward = True
    .Format = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying to modify the footnotes especially the numbering which is currently superscripted. Instead of superscripted number I need to have regular text in footnote (it's actually called a footnote reference in footnotes). Can you share some that would let me change just superscripted reference number only in footnotes (not rest of the document) to normal font? Thanks!

Comment: Footnotes are formatted using the Footnote Style. Footnote References are formatted using the Footnote Reference Style. There is no need to mess with their formatting aside from the proper use of those two Styles. Evidently, you've messed up the formatting. Re-applying the Styles is all it takes to correct that, not brute-force VBA code.

Comment: While I join macropod as a proponent of using styles, the Footnote Reference style applies to both the footnote number in the body of the document as well as the one in the footnote, itself.